# How to modify the object keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like following:

```
[{0: "value 0"},
{1: "value 1"},
{2: "value 2"},
{3: "value 3"}]
```

I want to modify it as following:

```
[{src: "value 0", alt:"value 0"},
{src: "value 1", alt:"value 1"}
{src: "value 2", alt:"value 2"}
{src: "value 3", alt:"value 3"}]
```

Do I need to create a new object to do so or I can modify the existing one ? I'm looking for the best solution.

Comment: You can add a value at a new key and delete the old key.

Comment: Use `myArray.map()` to change each item. This will return a new array instead of modifying the old one. Also be aware that `alt="value 0"` is invalid syntax inside an object.

Comment: Those aren't valid objects.

Comment: do you want only the values from the objects? what have you tried?

Comment: _"I'm looking for the best solution."_ What's your metric for best solution? A loop is often faster than an array method but array methods are more readable. Using a loop instead of an array method is usually considered bad practice even though it's a bit faster. For code golf the best solution is the shortest code.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do :

```js
let objs = [{0: "value 0"},
{1: "value 1"},
{2: "value 2"},
{3: "value 3"}];

for (let i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
  objs[i].src = objs[i][i];
  objs[i].alt = objs[i][i];
  delete objs[i][i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var aOldObject = [{0: "value 0"},{1: "value 1"},{2:"value 2"},{3: "value 3"}];
var aNewObject = aOldObject.map((o,i) => {
  return {
    src: o[i],
    alt: o[i]
  }
});

console.log(aNewObject);
```